# How can use 2 code same time like this

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

```
func rightWall()
{
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x - 283, self.frame.origin.y , self.size.width, self.size.height))
}
func leftWall()
{
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 283, self.frame.origin.y , self.size.width, self.size.height))
}
```

my codes here. when i use rightWall, leftWall is not work, when i use leftWall, right wall is not work. How can i use same time with 2 code? thanks for answers

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you define "not work" and add some extra details? (how you're trying to use those methods?)

Comment: Please explain better your question, are you trying to call the two codes at the same time?

Comment: My English unfortunately bad. so i want rightWall and leftWall fund same time work. but when i try only 1 fund is work. i try this method:
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
rightWall()
leftWall() }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special version of init method:

init(bodies: [AnyObject]) -> SKPhysicsBody, you can path two physics bodies from above.

You can also use  init(edgeChainFromPath path: CGPath!) -> SKPhysicsBody, but you can to create CGPath in such case.

Another alternative is to add two nodes, which body is right, left body correspondingly.

I think that first version is the best one. 
Remember that bodies, should not belong to other nodes, otherwise you'll get an exception. )

Comment: the path way will work but unfortunately you can't create group of bodies from edge-based ones